# Color individual vertices on a plane threejs

Tags: three.js, terrain, simplex-noise

I want to create a terrain generator with three.js and simplex noise, but I don't know how to color the vertices on the plane according to their biome. Here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var noise = new SimplexNoise();
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    camera.position.z = 100;
    var width, height, resolution, maxHeight, cameraDist;
    /*
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    */
    //write code here
    width = 100;
    height = 100;
    resolution = 50;
    maxHeight = 10;
    cameraDist = 1000;
    //write code here
    /*
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    */
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height, resolution, resolution);
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 5);
    scene.add(light);
    light.position.y = 10;
    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
    var xOff = 0.0;
    let i = 0;
    const WATER = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    const WOODLAND = 0x3f2a14;
    const MOUNTAIN = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
    const SNOW = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    for (let x = 0; x <= width; x += width / resolution){
      let yOff = 0.0;
      for (let y = 0; y <= height; y += height / resolution){
        let microHills = 0.03125 * noise.noise(32 * xOff, 32 * yOff)
        let extremelytinyHills = 0.0625 * noise.noise(16 * xOff, 16 * yOff);
        let verytinyHills = 0.125 * noise.noise(8 * xOff, 8 * yOff);
        let tinyHills = 0.25 * noise.noise(4 * xOff, 4 * yOff);
        let mediumHills = 0.5 * noise.noise(2 * xOff, 2 * yOff);
        let largeHills = noise.noise(xOff, yOff);
        let z = (microHills + extremelytinyHills + verytinyHills + tinyHills + mediumHills + largeHills) * maxHeight;
        geometry.vertices[i].z = z;
        let biome;
        if(Math.random() < 0.2){
          biome = WATER;
        }
        else if(Math.random() < 0.5){
          biome = WOODLAND;
        }
        else if(Math.random() < 0.6){
          biome = MOUNTAIN;
        }
        else if(Math.random() > 0.8){
          biome = SNOW;
        }
        //color???
        mat[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: biome});
        yOff ++;
        i ++;
      }
      xOff ++;
    }
    var Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.autoRotate = true;
    scene.add(Mesh);
    function loop(){
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heisters/1146b7f20149e1e3925b/raw/c5d6028df20a20e339bf8c9e1708422c42779495/three.orbitcontrols.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script>// Ported from Stefan Gustavson's java implementation
// http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf
// Read Stefan's excellent paper for details on how this code works.
//
// Sean McCullough banksean@gmail.com

/**
 * You can pass in a random number generator object if you like.
 * It is assumed to have a random() method.
 */
var SimplexNoise = function(r) {
 if (r == undefined) r = Math;
  this.grad3 = [[1,1,0],[-1,1,0],[1,-1,0],[-1,-1,0], 
                                 [1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[1,0,-1],[-1,0,-1], 
                                 [0,1,1],[0,-1,1],[0,1,-1],[0,-1,-1]]; 
  this.p = [];
  for (var i=0; i<256; i++) {
   this.p[i] = Math.floor(r.random()*256);
  }
  // To remove the need for index wrapping, double the permutation table length 
  this.perm = []; 
  for(var i=0; i<512; i++) {
  this.perm[i]=this.p[i & 255];
 } 

  // A lookup table to traverse the simplex around a given point in 4D. 
  // Details can be found where this table is used, in the 4D noise method. 
  this.simplex = [ 
    [0,1,2,3],[0,1,3,2],[0,0,0,0],[0,2,3,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,0], 
    [0,2,1,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,3,1,2],[0,3,2,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,3,2,0], 
    [0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0], 
    [1,2,0,3],[0,0,0,0],[1,3,0,2],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[2,3,0,1],[2,3,1,0], 
    [1,0,2,3],[1,0,3,2],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[2,0,3,1],[0,0,0,0],[2,1,3,0], 
    [0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0], 
    [2,0,1,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[3,0,1,2],[3,0,2,1],[0,0,0,0],[3,1,2,0], 
    [2,1,0,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[3,1,0,2],[0,0,0,0],[3,2,0,1],[3,2,1,0]];

this.dot = function(g, x, y) { 
 return g[0]*x + g[1]*y;
};

this.noise = function(xin, yin) { 
  var n0, n1, n2; // Noise contributions from the three corners 
  // Skew the input space to determine which simplex cell we're in 
  var F2 = 0.5*(Math.sqrt(3.0)-1.0); 
  var s = (xin+yin)*F2; // Hairy factor for 2D 
  var i = Math.floor(xin+s); 
  var j = Math.floor(yin+s); 
  var G2 = (3.0-Math.sqrt(3.0))/6.0; 
  var t = (i+j)*G2; 
  var X0 = i-t; // Unskew the cell origin back to (x,y) space 
  var Y0 = j-t; 
  var x0 = xin-X0; // The x,y distances from the cell origin 
  var y0 = yin-Y0; 
  // For the 2D case, the simplex shape is an equilateral triangle. 
  // Determine which simplex we are in. 
  var i1, j1; // Offsets for second (middle) corner of simplex in (i,j) coords 
  if(x0>y0) {i1=1; j1=0;} // lower triangle, XY order: (0,0)->(1,0)->(1,1) 
  else {i1=0; j1=1;}      // upper triangle, YX order: (0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1) 
  // A step of (1,0) in (i,j) means a step of (1-c,-c) in (x,y), and 
  // a step of (0,1) in (i,j) means a step of (-c,1-c) in (x,y), where 
  // c = (3-sqrt(3))/6 
  var x1 = x0 - i1 + G2; // Offsets for middle corner in (x,y) unskewed coords 
  var y1 = y0 - j1 + G2; 
  var x2 = x0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * G2; // Offsets for last corner in (x,y) unskewed coords 
  var y2 = y0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * G2; 
  // Work out the hashed gradient indices of the three simplex corners 
  var ii = i & 255; 
  var jj = j & 255; 
  var gi0 = this.perm[ii+this.perm[jj]] % 12; 
  var gi1 = this.perm[ii+i1+this.perm[jj+j1]] % 12; 
  var gi2 = this.perm[ii+1+this.perm[jj+1]] % 12; 
  // Calculate the contribution from the three corners 
  var t0 = 0.5 - x0*x0-y0*y0; 
  if(t0<0) n0 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t0 *= t0; 
    n0 = t0 * t0 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi0], x0, y0);  // (x,y) of grad3 used for 2D gradient 
  } 
  var t1 = 0.5 - x1*x1-y1*y1; 
  if(t1<0) n1 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t1 *= t1; 
    n1 = t1 * t1 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi1], x1, y1); 
  }
  var t2 = 0.5 - x2*x2-y2*y2; 
  if(t2<0) n2 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t2 *= t2; 
    n2 = t2 * t2 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi2], x2, y2); 
  } 
  // Add contributions from each corner to get the final noise value. 
  // The result is scaled to return values in the interval [-1,1]. 
  return 70.0 * (n0 + n1 + n2); 
};

// 3D simplex noise 
this.noise3d = function(xin, yin, zin) { 
  var n0, n1, n2, n3; // Noise contributions from the four corners 
  // Skew the input space to determine which simplex cell we're in 
  var F3 = 1.0/3.0; 
  var s = (xin+yin+zin)*F3; // Very nice and simple skew factor for 3D 
  var i = Math.floor(xin+s); 
  var j = Math.floor(yin+s); 
  var k = Math.floor(zin+s); 
  var G3 = 1.0/6.0; // Very nice and simple unskew factor, too 
  var t = (i+j+k)*G3; 
  var X0 = i-t; // Unskew the cell origin back to (x,y,z) space 
  var Y0 = j-t; 
  var Z0 = k-t; 
  var x0 = xin-X0; // The x,y,z distances from the cell origin 
  var y0 = yin-Y0; 
  var z0 = zin-Z0; 
  // For the 3D case, the simplex shape is a slightly irregular tetrahedron. 
  // Determine which simplex we are in. 
  var i1, j1, k1; // Offsets for second corner of simplex in (i,j,k) coords 
  var i2, j2, k2; // Offsets for third corner of simplex in (i,j,k) coords 
  if(x0>=y0) { 
    if(y0>=z0) 
      { i1=1; j1=0; k1=0; i2=1; j2=1; k2=0; } // X Y Z order 
      else if(x0>=z0) { i1=1; j1=0; k1=0; i2=1; j2=0; k2=1; } // X Z Y order 
      else { i1=0; j1=0; k1=1; i2=1; j2=0; k2=1; } // Z X Y order 
    } 
  else { // x0<y0 
    if(y0<z0) { i1=0; j1=0; k1=1; i2=0; j2=1; k2=1; } // Z Y X order 
    else if(x0<z0) { i1=0; j1=1; k1=0; i2=0; j2=1; k2=1; } // Y Z X order 
    else { i1=0; j1=1; k1=0; i2=1; j2=1; k2=0; } // Y X Z order 
  } 
  // A step of (1,0,0) in (i,j,k) means a step of (1-c,-c,-c) in (x,y,z), 
  // a step of (0,1,0) in (i,j,k) means a step of (-c,1-c,-c) in (x,y,z), and 
  // a step of (0,0,1) in (i,j,k) means a step of (-c,-c,1-c) in (x,y,z), where 
  // c = 1/6.
  var x1 = x0 - i1 + G3; // Offsets for second corner in (x,y,z) coords 
  var y1 = y0 - j1 + G3; 
  var z1 = z0 - k1 + G3; 
  var x2 = x0 - i2 + 2.0*G3; // Offsets for third corner in (x,y,z) coords 
  var y2 = y0 - j2 + 2.0*G3; 
  var z2 = z0 - k2 + 2.0*G3; 
  var x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0*G3; // Offsets for last corner in (x,y,z) coords 
  var y3 = y0 - 1.0 + 3.0*G3; 
  var z3 = z0 - 1.0 + 3.0*G3; 
  // Work out the hashed gradient indices of the four simplex corners 
  var ii = i & 255; 
  var jj = j & 255; 
  var kk = k & 255; 
  var gi0 = this.perm[ii+this.perm[jj+this.perm[kk]]] % 12; 
  var gi1 = this.perm[ii+i1+this.perm[jj+j1+this.perm[kk+k1]]] % 12; 
  var gi2 = this.perm[ii+i2+this.perm[jj+j2+this.perm[kk+k2]]] % 12; 
  var gi3 = this.perm[ii+1+this.perm[jj+1+this.perm[kk+1]]] % 12; 
  // Calculate the contribution from the four corners 
  var t0 = 0.6 - x0*x0 - y0*y0 - z0*z0; 
  if(t0<0) n0 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t0 *= t0; 
    n0 = t0 * t0 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi0], x0, y0, z0); 
  }
  var t1 = 0.6 - x1*x1 - y1*y1 - z1*z1; 
  if(t1<0) n1 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t1 *= t1; 
    n1 = t1 * t1 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi1], x1, y1, z1); 
  } 
  var t2 = 0.6 - x2*x2 - y2*y2 - z2*z2; 
  if(t2<0) n2 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t2 *= t2; 
    n2 = t2 * t2 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi2], x2, y2, z2); 
  } 
  var t3 = 0.6 - x3*x3 - y3*y3 - z3*z3; 
  if(t3<0) n3 = 0.0; 
  else { 
    t3 *= t3; 
    n3 = t3 * t3 * this.dot(this.grad3[gi3], x3, y3, z3); 
  } 
  // Add contributions from each corner to get the final noise value. 
  // The result is scaled to stay just inside [-1,1] 
  return 32.0*(n0 + n1 + n2 + n3); 
};
};</script>
```

This works, but I want to color the individual vertices, because you can't really see where the mountains are.
How do you color the vertices on a plane?

Comment: The order of scripts must be: 1. three.min.js, 2. OrbitControls.js. And it is highly recommended that they are of the same version/revision.

Comment: sorry, I just need to know how to color the vertices.